# Overwrite native date picker on mobile view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datepicker

Is there any way to overwrite the native date pickers on mobile view for a website?
I just want a normal field where users manually input their Date of Birth without any browser-specific widgets popping up.

I could not find anything on the internet.
Right now I`m using an input type="date" for the date field.

Is there any library that can help me?

Thank you in advance and sorry if my question is stupid. I`m kind of new to web development and still learning a lot of things.

Comment: try to look for `bootstrap-datepicker` it's simple and get the job done

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.